# NoMethodError in Users#new, undefined method `form_group_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods

I have read dozens of similar posts on no method errors, but I can't find one that fixes my problem.  I'm getting a `NoMethodError in Users#new` with the error message "undefined method 'form_group_tag' for #<#:0x007f8dbd7d97e8>".

My new.html.erb file code is:

```html
<!-- begin snippet -->
      <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
       <% if @user.errors.any? %>
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <h4><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
           <ul>
             <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
               <li><%= msg %></li>
             <% end %>
           </ul>
         </div>
       <% end %>
       <%= form_group_tag(@user.errors[:name]) do %>
         <%= f.label :name %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
       <% end %>
       <%= form_group_tag(@user.errors[:email]) do %>
         <%= f.label :email %>
         <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter email" %>
       <% end %>
       <%= form_group_tag(@user.errors[:password]) do %>
         <%= f.label :password %>
         <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password" %>
       <% end %>
       <%= form_group_tag(@user.errors[:password_confirmation]) do %>
         <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
         <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password confirmation" %>
       <% end %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
```

The error I'm getting is:
"undefined method 'form_group_tag' for #<#:0x007f8dbd7d97e8>"

My users controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = params[:user][:name]
    @user.email = params[:user][:email]
    @user.password = params[:user][:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome to Genetic Golf #{@user.name}!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error creating your account. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

In my routes.rb I have
`resources :users, only: [:new, :create]`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `form_group_tag` and I couldn't find it referenced in the Guide for Form Helpers. Where does it come from?

Comment: That's because it was supposed to be in a helper that I forgot to include.  Thank you!